# Scale down an image dynamically

Tags: svg

In my SVG picture there are some text labels that are displayed dynamically in top part of the image. In some cases (i.e. smaller screen size, bigger font size), they partially disappear outside the vievBox (like if `overflow: hidden;` was set) - see the picture (the long word in the middle is the overflowing label).

[image: illustration of the issue]

My idea is to scale down the image so that the labels are visible. How to achieve this?

Comment: make the viewBox bigger.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I had quite wide bottom margin, so I could afford moving the whole image down to uncover the top part.

Final solution was wrapping the whole image with `<g transform="translate(0,10)">`.

The first value refers to left-right movement, the other one to up-down (positive values move the image down, negative - up).